# Merge XML Strings in Java without File intermediary

Tags: java, xml, xinclude

I am currently using XInclude to merge XML files. However, I am moving these XMLs from a filesystem to a database where they are saved as Strings. What is the best way to merge these XML strings without using Files as an intermediary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect input streams of the file to the output stream of the database.
In order to merge input streams, just use `java.io.SequenceInputStream(i1, i2)`

```
new SequenceInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlFile1), new FileInputStream(xmlFile2))
// use merged inputStream
```

Comment: By merging I specifically mean XML merging - avoid duplication of shared roots and properties and appending the rest. Not just a simple concatenation

Comment: Oh, I got you. I do not see any other way except reading the whole content of both files and merge them in the memory.